# el[0].append('<div> </div>') выводит строку, а не добавляет элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Друзья, подскажите, есть задача добавить после определенных элементов нужный элемент. Я подставляю его так `el[0].append('<div> elem </div>')` но append в этом случае выводит на страницу `<div> elem </div>` а не добавляет элемент div с содержанием "Элемент".
Я что-то делаю не так?

```js
$('.app')[1].append('<div> elem </div>')
$('.app')[3].append('<div> elem </div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">Тут текст 1</div>
<div class="app">Тут текст 2</div>
<div class="app">Тут текст 3</div>
<div class="app">Тут текст 4</div>
```

Comment: Используя конструкцию типа `$('.element')[0]` , вы выбираете dom-элемент, который не обладает методами jQuery объекта. Для корректной работы вашего примера используйте конструкцию  `$('.element').eq(1).append('<div> elem </div/>')`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Очень помогли!

Comment: Используйте `$('.app').eq(1).append('<div>elem</div>');`

Answer (score 2):

Такой способ делает выборку 1 раз, не вызывая доп. функций по фильтрации у уже найденного элемента:

```js
$('.app:nth-child(3)').after('<div>elem</div>');
$('.app:nth-child(5)').after('<div>elem 2</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">Тут текст 1</div>
<div class="app">Тут текст 2</div>
<div class="app">Тут текст 3</div>
<div class="app">Тут текст 4</div>
```

P.S.

> задача добавить после определенных элементов нужный элемент

Для того, чтобы добавить "**ПОСЛЕ**" элемента используйте `after` вместо `append`. Последний добавляет "**В**" конец самого элемента.

Comment: Да, я неправильно указал, что нужно в конец поставить, а не после.

Comment: @Kvilios ,  тут ещё надо знать что автор хочет найти: n-ый элемент среди всех удовлетворяющих селектору или элементы n-ые по порядку среди своих соседей.

Answer (score 0):

Частично решается подставлением переменной

```
div = $("<div />",{
    text: "elem"
 });
```

Но это слишком громоздко создавать объект для такой ситуации. Может есть решение получше?

Comment: На всякий случай замечу, что `div` запрещено делать самозакрывающимся и код `<div />` некорректен; правильный `<div></div>`. Хотя в данном конкретном примере это роли не играет